# How to check if socket is connected or not using background thread

Tags: java, android, sockets

i am developing application in which i am checking availability of port before reading and writing on socket. i am using following code to check status

```
private boolean isAvailable(String host, int port) {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket();
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), 1000);
            isPortAvailable = socket.isConnected();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            isPortAvailable = false;
        }
        return isPortAvailable;
    }
```

After this i am checking this status on `onClick()`

```
if (isAvailable(ip, Integer.parseInt(portLVR))) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityLivingRoom.class));
} else
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connection Error !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

but my problem is if i check this status on main thread then android will give me `networkonMainThradException` so how do i manage this operation using background thread?

Comment: Can't you use AsyncTask for it or a separate thread..?

Comment: @Pragnani,how do i use AsyncTask like a method  which returns boolean value ?

Comment: take a boolean field and assign it a value returned by isAvailble method in doinBackground..What's wrong with that.. let me know.?

Comment: @Pragnani but on each of button click i am passing different IP in that method, how do i manage this with AsynckTask ?

Comment: Check my answer...That should work

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 private class SocketCheckTask extends AsyncTask<String , Integer , Boolean> {
       String classname="";
     public SocketCheckTask (String classname) {
              this.classname=classname;
    } 
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
    return isAvailable(params[0], Integer.parseInt(params[1]);
  }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isAvailable) {
   if (isAvailable)) {
     Class c=Class.forName("yourpackage"+classname);
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),c));
     } else
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connection Error !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
}
```

And send it like this

```
 SocketCheckTask task=new SocketCheckTask ("ActivityLivingRoom");
task.execute(ipadress,port);
```

Comment: @thanks but still i am confused with one thing,as ip chages starting activity will also changed , i don't want to open `ActivityLivingRoom.class` activity each time

Comment: how do i call `startActivity()` method from `AsynkTask's` `postExecute()` method ?

Comment: @juned Why do you think you can't..? I have already given in the answer check

Comment: i mean if i use separate `AsynkTask` class

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
private class CheckAvailabilityTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    String ip;
    int port;

    public CheckAvailabilityTask(String ip, int port) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return isAvailable(this.ip, this.port);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isAvailable) {
        if (iisAvailable) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityLivingRoom.class));
        } else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connection Error !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And in `onClick()` event:

```
new CheckAvailabilityTask(IP, PORT).execute();
```

Comment: @Thanks but i want to do this check for multiple buttons, so where should i pass my ip in this AsynkTask ? and this class gives me error like `The return type is incompatible with AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean>`

Comment: Check my updated answer, doInbackground should return Boolean, before it was String that was being returned

Comment: thanks but still i am confused with one thing, i don't want to open `ActivityLivingRoom.class` activity each time, that should also be changed

Comment: what do you mean by that? You can create a separate class CheckAvailabilityTask and call it from any other acitivity requireds

Comment: @Waqas He may want asynctask as separate class, not inner class

Comment: @Pragnani using Asynctask it take too much time to open new activity

Comment: @juned Don't worry it will take less time in mobile..Don't be there in a feeling that asynctask will consume more time, instead it will make your app fast

Answer (score 0):

I think best solution would be, start a new thread on click event and putting your start activity code inside the same thread.

If you are using toast you can do it from that thread but if you plan to update UI (like red/green status) you have to use handler and messages.

FYI, Asynctask just remove the implementation of Thread and shows people a nice abstraction.

Comment: Asyctask is designed for updating UI, i am not seeing you are updating UI anywhere. But yehh definitely you can use Asynctask.

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a socket and never close it just to establish whether a host:port is available.

The only real way to test whether any service or resource is available is to try to use it.

Just do the connect, and the I/O, when you need to do them, and handle the resulting exceptions at that point. You have to catch them anyway.

Don't write code that tries to predict the future.

Comment: Actually i want to check if connection is available or not before starting an activity which doing socket I/O.

Comment: That's exactly what I have just told you not to do. What you should be doing is (a) attempting to connect and (b) attempting to read or write. There is no such concept as 'connection is available'. And what your *code* actually does is create a socket and then throw it away. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I got your point thanks but still i want to know is there any other way to know if socket is open or closed ?

Comment: @juned The question is ambiguous. The *Socket* is open if `Socket.isClosed()` returns false. That tells you whether *you* have ever closed the *Socket.* However the *connection* between this socket and the peer's socket can be in any state at all, and the only way in TCP you can find out is by writing to it or reading from it. There is no API.

Comment: i have number of buttons in one activity and on ON|OFF of that button i am writing a byte of array on socket, as well as i have another thread which continuously writes and reads on same socket to check the status on same activity. so before opening any activity i just want to check if that socket is connected or not. what will you suggest in this case, my application is too slow please give me some idea. thanks

Comment: @juned I've answered that. Just try it and handle the exception. What you are asking is how to predict the future. You can't.

Comment: you are correct but in my case i have to find the status of socket if i could be connected or not.

Comment: @juned I don't get it. I am correct, but you 'have to' do it anyway, even though it can't be done, shouldn't be done, won't be done.

Comment: @juned *Either* I am correct or you 'have to' do it. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: then what's the final solution for this, here is the [image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621106/android-how-do-i-create-this-type-of-layout) please see, bottom buttons are for different rooms. if connection is not available then i don't want user to go in particular room.